# WPF changing button background color when the window is disabled

Tags: wpf, listview, textbox, transparency, button

I have a button with a transparent background on a wpf window.

Problem is, when I open up another window with a .showdialog the form becomes disabled as does the button, causing the button to go white (and stick out like a sore thumb); the same happens to the listview and textbox controls.  Labels and group boxes aren't impacted in this way and remain looking fine.

How do I preserve the transparency color of the button, listview and textboxes when they are disabled?

Thanks, Rob

Comment: Can you post your XAML?  Are you using custom styles or templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your button template looks like, I would recommend posting your XAML.  But check out the MSDN Docs on [Button Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx)